# MySQL Rollup with multiple levels

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy

Hello I am attempting to do a roll-up of an x number of levels.  The hierarchy is something like this:

```
1 - Total Depth 1
1.1, 1.2, 1.3 - Depth 2
1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.2.1, 1.2.2 - Depth 3
```

And so on and so forth...

I thought of using a Substring Index to compare and rollup but I can't seem to figure out how to formulate the query to not care how many levels there are.

For example if I want 1.1.1, I would also like to retrieve 1.1 and 1.  Getting all the results would show the drill-down classification.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I am currently using as a workaround
Path is the 1, 1.1, 1.1.1 field

```
IF(depth=3, SUBSTRING(path, 1, 3) , SUBSTRING(path, 1, 1)) as `Depth3`,
IF(depth=2, SUBSTRING(path, 1, 5) , SUBSTRING(path, 1, 1)) as `Depth2`
```

This will give me 1.1 and 1 along with the path field of 1.1.1 but it required me to specify the depth.

Comment: You should mention in your question that you don't want solutions depend on the application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that SEMSEM, I want solutions that work for MySQL.

Comment: I mean that hierarchy may be maintained through the application, i.e PHP, ASP.net, etc. so, if you want a solution that uses SQL select statement only, it is preferable to mention this clearly in the question.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input data and results that you are looking for?  I can't quite figure out what the question is.

Comment: Sorry about that! The input data will just be the scheme depth so if I chose depth 3, I will need to have all the 1.1.x's returned with 1.1 and 1.  Retrieving those results without specifying the number of levels is the tricky part.